# Animating a rotating disk

Tags: graphics, animation

I have a system with 3 degrees of freedom that I want to know if it is possible to visualise with `Mathematica` in the two-dimensional $X-Y$ plane. I have a plane circular object rotating at its set speed say $10$ deg/s. This object is not rotating at the $(0, 0)$ origin point but is displaced from the origin $(0, 0)$ coordinates and its motion path is described by

$x=x_0 + a \times \cos(\omega \: t)$ and $y=a \times \sin(\omega \: t)$

Some values: $x_0 = 1$ mm; $a=0.25$ mm, $\omega=10$ deg/s (same as the rotating speed of the circular object). The radius of the circular object can be taken to be a couple of cm say $2$ cm.

The time parameter $t$ in the parametric equations can be discretised in $20$ steps as follows:

$\mathrm{step}= \frac{360 \; \mathrm{deg}}{\omega \times 20} = \frac{360}{10 \times 20}=1.8$ s

so that $\mathrm{step}$ will take values $0$, $1.8$, $3.6$, $\ldots$, $34.2$ s.

Thus the product $\omega \: t$ as the cosine and sine arguments of the parametric path can be written as

$\omega \: t = \omega \times \frac{\mathrm{step \times \pi}}{180}$

which in units gives $\frac{\mathrm{deg}}{\mathrm{seconds}} \times \frac{\mathrm{seconds} \times \mathrm{radians}}{\mathrm{deg}} = \mathrm{radians}$.

Any help will be appreciated to this `Mathematica` newbie on how to go about to simulate this kind of motion. Desired animation fatures:

1. Perhaps the circular object can have **hatched shading** so that its rotating motion can be seen on top of its following the parametric circular path;
2. The $x-$ and $y-$axes should be visible;
3. The parametric path given by the parametric equations in $x$ and $y$ should be visible as a circle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lets start with some parameters (note that I've chosen larger values for `a` and `x0` here to actually see the movement of the centre)

```
radius = 20;
x0 = 10;
a = 5;
om1 = 10 Degree; 
om2 = 10 Degree;
```

The centre of the rotating object at time `t` is given by

```
centre[t_] := {x0 + a Cos[om1 t], a Sin[om1 t]};
```

I'm using `RegionPlot` to create an image of the disk centred at the origin

```
circ = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= radius^2, {x, -radius, radius}, 
  {y, -radius, radius}, 
  Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}}, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
  PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next, we're defining a function for creating the plot at time `t`. I'm using `Rotate` and `Translate` to get the orientation and position of the disk. The path of the centre is plotted using `ParametricPlot`

```
plot[t_] := Show[Graphics[
  Translate[Rotate[{circ[[1]], Point[{0, 0}]}, om2 t], centre[t]]],
  If[Abs[t] <= $MachineEpsilon, {},
    ParametricPlot[centre[s], {s, 0, t}, PlotStyle -> {Black}]],
  PlotRange -> {{-2 radius, 2 radius}, {-2 radius, 2 radius}}, 
  Axes -> True]
```

Plugging this function into `Animate` will create an animation of this function:

```
Animate[plot[t], {t, 0, 36}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

You should try something like

```
omega=10 Degree;
x0=1;
a=0.25;
ParametricPlot[{x0+a Cos[omega t],a Sin[omega t]},{t,0,2 Pi /omega}]
```

This gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit** For viewing as a varied time step:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{x0 + a Cos[omega t], a Sin[omega t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> {{.5, 1.5}, {-.5, .5}}]
, {tmax, $MachineEpsilon, 2 Pi/omega}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Also Edit** If you want "full control" over the various options, try something like

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{x0 + a Cos[omega t], y0 + a Sin[omega t]}, {t, 0,tmax},
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}],
 {{x0, 1}, -2, 2}, {{y0, 0}, -2, 2}, {{a, 0.25}, 0,3},
 {tmax, $MachineEpsilon, 2 Pi/omega}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Also also edit** Hopefully this is closer to what you're looking for?

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{x0 + a Cos[omega t], y0 + a Sin[omega t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
   Epilog -> {
    Circle[{x0 + a Cos[omega tmax], a Sin[omega tmax]},circlerad],
    Line[{{x0 + a Cos[omega tmax],a Sin[omega tmax]}, {x0 + a Cos[omega tmax], 
    a Sin[omega tmax]} + 
    circlerad {Cos[omega tmax], Sin[omega tmax]}}]}],
 {{x0, 1}, -2, 2}, {{y0, 0}, -2, 2}, {{a, 0.25}, 0,3}, 
 {{circlerad, 2}, 0, 3}, {tmax, $MachineEpsilon, 2 Pi/omega}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: See the addition I made.

Comment: @yCalleecharan Assuming I understand what you're saying, I remember seeing an undocumented feature for changing the plot style based on the number of times it goes around, but I can't seem to find it at the moment.

Comment: Wait, unless by "hatched shading" you mean `PlotStyle->Dashed`? You want something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yZl1Z.png)?