# Adding a point to an already existing graphic

Tags: graphics

This is just a follow-up of this post:

[Animating a rotating disk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1592/beginner-2d-animation-with-maths-equations)

Part of the code is:

```
circ = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= radius^2, {x, -radius, radius}, 
{y, -radius, radius}, 
Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}}, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
PlotStyle -> None]
```

where `radius = 20`.

Say that I would like to add a **big dot** at the coordinates `(10,10)` on the above disc. My code is:

```
circ2 = Show[circ, 
Epilog -> Inset[ListPlot[{10, 10}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.025]] ]
```

This however does not work.

Can anyone suggest how to add a point on an already made graphic and **save the combined graphic as a single new object**?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
radius = 20;

circ = RegionPlot[
  x^2 + y^2 <= radius^2, {x, -radius, radius}, {y, -radius, radius}, 
  Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> {{Red}, {Blue}}, BoundaryStyle -> Black, 
  PlotStyle -> None]

circ2 = Show[circ, Graphics[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{10, 10}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could have used `ListPlot` too, but the point here is that `Show` combined `Graphics` into a new `Graphics`, so you need to feed it with Graphics (`ListPlot` returns a `Graphics` object)

```
circ3 = Show[circ, 
  ListPlot[{{10, 10}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.025]]]
```

Another option perhaps more similar to what you were trying could be

```
Show[circ, Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{10, 10}}]}]
```

`Graphics` are composed of primitives, directives and options. 
Primitives are the shapes (`Line`, `Point`, `Circle`, etc). 
Directives are stuff that affect the shapes, such as color settings, point size, line type, arrow heads, etc. In the same `Graphic` object you can combine several directives, affecting different primitives (a red circle with a black dot)
Options are general to the graphic. `AspectRatio`, stuff about the axes, etc..

So, a `Graphics` object is `Graphics[{list of primitives and directives}, options]`

What `Show` does is take several `Graphics`, combine its primitives and directives, and optionally change the general options.

`PlotStyle` is an option for functions that automatically create `Graphics`, like `Plot` and his family. It is NOT a `Graphics` option. In those functions, it allows among other things to set directives to the stuff you're plotting. So if you're used to writing `Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle->something, otheroptions->othervalues]` then that something is probably a directive. And probably, otheroptions are general graphic options (or other particular options of the plotting function such as `Filling`, etc).

So, let's see what you were trying to do with your code

```
Show[circ, 
Epilog -> Inset[ListPlot[{10, 10}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.025]] ]
```

You were trying to create a new `Graphics` with the same primitives and directives than circ, but with an extra option `Epilog`. Furthermore, you were trying to add as options to the `Graphics` something that is not an option :P. 
`Epilog` just adds more primitives to the `Graphics` object after it is rendered. It is more or less the same as adding more primitives to the list, except that it allows to do it as an option so it's convenient to add annotations in functions such as `Plot`. The fact that they are added after the `Graphics` was rendered also means you can mix 2D and 3D primitives. No different in your case than writing the following

```
Show[circ, Graphics[{Inset[ListPlot[{10, 10}]]}]]
```

Moving on. `Inset` takes a `Graphics`, `Image`, cell expression, string, etc, and turns it into a primitive. So, the `Graphics` object generated by `ListPlot` now is taken as a whole, with it's own set of axes and everything, and combined with the primitives of circ. Not what you wanted

Final comment. `ListPlot` if it's given a one dimensional list, interprets all the numbers as y-coordinates. If you want it to plot (x,y) pairs, you need to give it a list of (x, y) pairs. In your case, a list of only one pair,  `{{10, 10}}`

Hope that now you not only understand why your code didn't work but also why what works works

Comment: @yCalleecharan, just edited to explain a little bit more of what I believe to know (I'm not an expert on this area). Glad to help