# Adding a circle to an already existing drawing

Tags: graphics

With reference to my earlier post:

[Adding a point to an already existing graphic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1675/adding-a-point-to-an-already-existing-graphic)

I would like to add an outer circle to the whole drawing. This outer circle is a fixed one of `radius 40`. Something like this is helpful:

```
Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 40]]
```

But I do not know exactly where to put it in my code so that it remain a fixed circle in the background.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Does adding `PlotRange->All` help? (I cannot test at the moment). I think the problem is that show takes the options (including the plot range) is taken from the first argument, and that's too small to see the circle. Another thing you could do is to put the large circle first (because AFAICS it doesn't intersect with the `RegionPlot` anyway).

Comment: If you posted actual working code showing the problem, the chances would be better that anyone understands what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a large enough PlotRange, or

```
circ11 = Show[circ, Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 40]], PlotRange -> All]
```

Edit: are you referring to Heike's code? If so, you could simply replace her plot[t] function 
by something like:

```
plot[t_] := 
 Show[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 40], 
    Translate[Rotate[{circ[[1]], Point[{0, 0}]}, om2 t], centre[t]]}],
   If[Abs[t] <= $MachineEpsilon, {}, 
   ParametricPlot[centre[s], {s, 0, t}, PlotStyle -> {Black}]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-2 radius, 2 radius}, {-2 radius, 2 radius}}, 
  Axes -> True]
```

and the outer circle will be visible and not fixed.