# How to put single points inside the plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I wrote this simple code for a basic plot (two lines):

```
Plot[{4, 0}, {x, -2, 2},   
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.004]}, {Red, Dashed, 
    Thickness[0.004]}}, PlotRange -> {-1, 6}]
```

Whose output is simply

[image]

I would like to insert a single point (and moreover, I would like that that point were clearly visible, quite marked) for example the point $P = (1, 4)$ on the red higher line.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1675/5478

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Plot[{4, 0}, {x, -2, 2},
 Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize@Large, Point[{1, 4}]},
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.004]}, {Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.004]}},
 PlotRange -> {-1, 6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome again! Easy and fast, thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

Another option is to use `Show` and `Graphics`, as in

```
p = Plot[{4, 0}, {x, -2, 2},PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.004]}, {Red, Dashed, 
      Thickness[0.004]}}, PlotRange -> {-1, 6}];
g = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{1, 4}]}];
Show[p, g]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]