# How to add the legend for one point on the plot

Tags: plotting, syntax, legending

Consider we want to add one point on the plot with some legend (see the [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101660/how-to-put-single-points-inside-the-plot)). How to add the separate legend for this point? How to add the legend for many points at the plot?

Thank you.

Comment: By legend, do you mean a text or a symbol?

Comment: @Sumit : a text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html).

```
p1 = {Pi/2, 1}; txt1 = "Max";
p2 = {3 Pi/2, -1}; txt2 = "Min";
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Point[p1], Text[txt1, p1 + {0, -0.1}], Point[p2], Text[txt2, p2 + {0, 0.1}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, this could be a starting point by using `Callout`:

```
Plot[{Callout[Log[x] Sin[x], "P1", {2, Log[2] Sin[2]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Italic], FrameMargins -> 7, 
CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint", Appearance -> "Leader"], 
Callout[Log[x] Sin[x], "P2", {5, Log[5] Sin[5]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Italic], FrameMargins -> 7, 
CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint", Appearance -> "Leader"]}, {x, 0, 
2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> {-2, 1}]
```

[image]